# Split Firebase key-value pairs into seperate arrays

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im working on a star-rating system where users can rate a certain item from one to five stars, as well as see the average star rating of all users.

So far I've been able to send the user rating to my firebase database where the key-value pair consists of the users ID and their given rating as a Double. I'm also able to retreive said data and print it to the console, however the problem is that I only need the rating doubles in a new array in order to calculate average rating; not the user ID String that comes with it.

How can I separate the User ID string and rating given Double, so I can work with only the rating numbers?

I've tried creating a new empty array and appending the score Double from Firebase into it many different ways, however none seem to work and I cannot figure out why.

Using the following code I am able to print out the key-value pairs of the item (sentData1)

```
        handle = ref.child(sentData1).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)

    })
```

Update: I managed to get what I wanted using this bit of code:

```
ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let values = Array(data.values)

            print(values)
        }
    }
```

However, I now get an odd issue: when first launching the app and giving different items a rating, it works perfectly displaying all the ratings the item has gotten in an array format [2, 5, 3, 4]. However, as i go on to rate more items, it randomly starts giving me the array two times, then three and so on for the same item like this:

```
[4, 2, 3, 4]
```

[4, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 2, 3, 4]

and after some time it eventually crashes giving me the error message

```
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

in the line of code that writes data to the Firebase database:

```
userDB.child(sentData2).child(UserID!).setValue(cosmosRating!)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dict = ["userId1" : 2.4, "userId2" : 2.0, "userId3": 4.5]
```

You can simply do

```
let array = Array(dict.values)
print(array)

// Prints [2.0, 2.4, 4.5]
```

Comment: That would be a good solution, yes. However my problem is I am not able to divide the user ID and Double values intro separate groups of data, so I'm not able to add them into dictionaries. 

The only way I'm able to access the user ID and the Double is using snapshot, but this keyword gives me both values together.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**

I haven't tested it yet hope it helps you, but it would look something like this.
I would first create a user object

```
class User: NSObject {

   public var userID: String!
   public var rating: Double!

   // default constructor
   convenience override init() {
       self.init(userID: " ", rating: 0.0)
   }

    // copy constructor
    init(userID: String, rating: Double) {
        self.userID = userID
        self.rating = rating
    }
}
```

then initialize an object array

```
var userArray = [User]()
```

and to get all users data from firebase

```
ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    for user in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
        for userChild in user.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
            let tempUser = userChild.value as! [String:AnyObject]
            let id= tempUser["USER_ID"] as! String
            let star = tempUser["RATING"] as! Double

            let x = userArray(userID: id, rating: star)
            print("user id: \(x.userID) \n star rating: \(x.rating)")
             self.userArray.append(x)

        }
    }
})
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This bit of code gives me an error: "Cannot call value of non-function type '[User]'" at let x = userArray(userID: id, rating: Double(star))

Comment: there's a typo somewhere